# SQL Server Jobs- Environment Variables- SSIS packages

Tags: sql-server, ssis, environment-variables, production-environment, job-scheduling

[image]

I've deployed some SSIS packages into SQL server and created jobs that would run at certain intervals of time. Sometimes, the jobs are failing and the reason I find in the description is  that the environment variables checkbox is getting unchecked i.e., no environment is specified for the step/job to get executed. This is causing serious trouble..is there any setting in SQL server which would retain the checkbox left ticked??If so, answer with a screenshot would be highly helpful I don't know why it is getting unchecked everytime.

Comment: "no environment is specified for the step/job to get executed." Are you trying to set the Dev, QA, UAT, and Prod through this? Please clarify.

Comment: What would help us help you is for you to post some screenshots of what exactly you are trying to achieve.

Comment: I added the snapshot in the question itself..and pointed arrow marks to the checkboxes that are getting unchecked everytime. pl click on the link in the question..when I go and  tick the checkboxes and run..everything is fine..it's a production issue

Comment: what do you mean by "unchecked ever time"?  You manually create a job, add a step, check those options, job runs fine.  Then some point after that the job randomly loses/unchecks those options and the job starts failing?

Comment: Yes exactly that's what is happening